# What browsers support Java 8?

Tags: java, applet, java-8

I have looked at the Oracle website but it doesn't have a system requirements page for Java 8 yet, so I'm not sure to find this information?

Edit: Sorry, I mean to be able to run a Java Applet.

Comment: i don't understand the question. why would a browser support java?

Comment: Browsers do not support Java. If you mean if you can write a Web Application using Java 8, the answer is yes, you can.

Answer (score 0):

Java 7 doesn't specify which browsers are supported. It is left to the browsers individually to support Java.

https://www.java.com/en/download/help/sysreq.xml

Comment: For Java 7 it has "Browsers: Internet Explorer 7.0 and above, Firefox 3.6 and above, Chrome", I wanted to know if this was the same for Java 8.